# Como copiar dados de uma planilha para outra com VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou com um problema para copiar dados de uma planilha para outra, pois ou ele não roda ou simplesmente não copia, então, agora estou utiilizando o código abaixo, porém dá erro na definição do lr, será que poderiam me ajudar, desde já agradeço
Situação: Gostaria de copiar os dados da D8 até a última célula utilizada e colar na segunda aba da B3 em diante, somente isso, porém estou com uma dificuldade, o código tentado mais recente foi.:

```
Sub CopyCurrentRegion()

   Dim dest As Worksheet

Dim lr As String

   Dim Source As Worksheet

   Set dest = Sheets("Receita Projetos")

   Set Source = Sheets("Análise de Wip")

   lr = Worksheets("Análise de Wip").Range("D8" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

   dest.Range("B3" & lr).Value = Source.Range("D8").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia,

Segue código que pode ajudar:

```
Sub CopyCurrentRegion()
    Dim dest As Worksheet
    Dim lr As Variant
    Dim source As Worksheet

    Set dest = Sheets("Receita Projetos")
    Set source = Sheets("Análise de wip")

    ultimalinha = source.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    lr = source.Range("D8:D" & ultimalinha)

    dest.Range("B3:B" & UBound(lr)) = lr

End Sub
```

Comment: Então, primeiramente obrigado por tentar ajudar, porém esse UBound, ele diz que era esperado uma matriz, antes ele dizia que o df não estava definido porém defini ele como long já que o UBound retorna um long(me corrija por favor caso esteja errado)

Comment: Desculpe, realmente estava com um incoerencia no código, eu alterei as variáveis. Corrigi agora, o Ubound é na variável lr fica Ubound(lr). O Ubound retorna o tamanho do vetor ou matriz, por isso a variável que deve estar dentro neste caso é o lr.

Comment: Olá muito obrigado pela ajuda, porém uma outra dúvida, caso eu queira fazer com mais colunas, teria que repetir tudo de novo ou eu poderia simplesmente adaptar meu código?

Comment: Se forem colunas em sequencia, você pode ajustar o código para o lr capturar uma matriz, neste caso só necessitaria de ajuste, caso sejam colunas separadas teria de fazer uma a uma, pois seria necessário contar a quantidade de linhas de cada uma.

Comment: Ah sim perfeito, muito obrigado pela ajuda